# How to insert multiple rows based on selected values but without corresponding value size on the other variable

Tags: php

I am trying out multiple selection inserts where one input is singular and the multi-selection has more values. This is only working to insert one record and am struggling to find a way of mapping the values of studentIDs to one tutorID as follows:

```
tutorUserID   studentUserID
        1             2
        1             4
        1             5
```

Html

```
<input type="text" name="tutorUserID" id="tutorUserID"  value="1"/>

<select name="studentUserID[]" id="studentUserID" multiple>
        <option value="">------- Select Students-------</option> 
        <option value="2">Student A</option> 
        <option value="4">Student B</option> 
        <option value="5">Student C</option> 
</select>
```

Posted as:

```
tutorUserID: 1
studentUserID[]:[...]
                0:2
                1:4
                2:5
```

PHP Insertion query

```
$tutorUserID = $_POST['tutorUserID'];
$studentUserID=$_POST['studentUserID'];

$stmt = $con -> prepare("INSERT INTO assigns(StudentUserID,TutorUserID) VALUES (:studentUserID,:tutorUserID)");
foreach($_POST['studentUserID'] as $key => $studentUserIDs)
                        {   
$stmt->bindValue(':studentUserID', $studentUserIDs);
$stmt->bindValue(':tutorUserID', $tutorUserID[$key]);       
                        }   
$stmt->execute();
```

This implementation is only inserting one row because tutorUserID only has one value. Is there a way in which I can achieve inserting all values?

Answer (score 1):

The execute need to be inside the loop.

And you can use `$_POST['tutorUserID']` because `$tutorUserID[$key]` was not an array and in fact you only need the same value in all the inserts

```
$studentUserID=$_POST['studentUserID'];

$stmt = $con -> prepare("INSERT INTO assigns (StudentUserID,TutorUserID) 
                                    VALUES (:studentUserID,:tutorUserID)");

foreach($_POST['studentUserID'] as $studentUserIDs) {   
    $stmt->bindValue(':studentUserID', $studentUserIDs);
    $stmt->bindValue(':tutorUserID', $_POST['tutorUserID']);  
    $stmt->execute();     
}
```